# Can MySQL INSERT Query be run out of order

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064

I am attempting to run:

```
INSERT INTO orders ('id','datetime','server','price','comment','addons','table_number','Omelet','Pancakes','Crepes','Salad','Steak_Sandwich','Chicken_Quesadilla','BLT','Prime_Rib','Pineapple_Upside_Down_Cake') VALUES ('','18/9/11 6:49:03PM','admin','0', 'N/A','None','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')
```

and phpmyadmin columheaders look like:

```
    id  datetime    server  price   comment addons  table_number    Omelet  Steak_Sandwich  Chicken_Quesadilla  BLT Salad   Prime_Rib   Crepes  Pancakes    Pineapple_Upside_Down_Cake
```

and is returning:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near
>   ''id','datetime','server','price','comment','addons','table_number','Omelet','Pan'
>   at line 1

Can I do this out of order like I have it and if so can anyone spot my error
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you perhaps have come up with a simpler (i.e. shorter) example for the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as `id` is a column name - you need to remove single quotes and replace them with backticks

```
INSERT INTO orders (`id`, `datetime`, ...
```

Also you can remove backticks too and specify `id` as-is, but this can cause an issue if your column name has the same name as one of mysql's keywords, such as `from`

UPD: As someone pointed in the comments (sorry, I don't remember your name and the comment has been already deleted) - if `id` is an autoincrement field, then you can avoid specifying it at all (if so - don't forget to remove its value (empty string) from values list too)

Comment: Thanks i tried that but everywhere and was getting a WSOD from the php probably changed something I shouldn't have in a var

Comment: @CCG121: uhm, what? Look at the logs and turn on errors output.